# How do I in AngularJS add two different events to a dom depending if is mobile or not

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to rewrite my application from being based on a ton of jQuery Widgets to use AngularJS. I am however having trouble finding the best solution to the following problem.

I have an image, which will show an overlay when hovering. To make it work on mobile devices, I instead use a click event to display the hover and to remove it again.

In jQuery I would look at the userAgent and then either add a click event for mobile devices, or for other devices user regular hover effect.

What is the correct way of doing this in AngularJS, without having to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is only a framework, not a DOM library, so you would still have to use jQuery.

You would create a custom directive for this. In the example below, I call it `image-overlay`.

```
<img src="foobar.png" image-overlay />
```

And then define your directive:

```
app.directive('imageOverlay', function() {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // element here is the img object to which you added the directive
      // use jQuery here to check user agent and apply the correct event.
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current unstable version of angular there is basic support for mobile devices:

Example: [`ngTap`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ngMobile.directive%3angTap)